# Insert vector or string into an individual matrix cell

Tags: r

I would like to make a matrix/array in which one cell contains 4 numbers so that if I use the length() function on a given cell that it will return the number of observations = 4.

Any help is appreciated..

```
battery <- read.table ( text = "
1 15 130 155 74 180
1 70 34 40 80 75
1 125 20 70 82 58
2 15 150 188 159 126
2 70 126 122 106 115
2 125 25 70 58 45
3 15 138 110 168 160
3 70 174 120 150 139
3 125 96 104 82 60      
")

colnames(battery) <-c("Material","Temperature","First Observation","Second Observation","Third Observation","Fourth Observation")
as.matrix(battery)

life.obs <- array(NA,c(3,3))
as.data.frame(life.obs)

count=0

for (i in 1:nrow(life.obs)) 
{
  life15 <- c(battery[i,3],battery[i,4],battery[i,5],battery[i,6])
  life70 <- c(battery[i+3,3],battery[i+3,4],battery[i+3,5],battery[i+3,6])
  life125 <- c(battery[i+6,3],battery[i+6,4],battery[i+6,5],battery[i+6,6])

  life.obs[i,count+1] <- as.vector(life15) #this is where I am stuck
  life.obs[i,count+2] <- as.vector(life70) 
  life.obs[i,count+3] <- as.vector(life125)

  count=0
}
```

Comment: you can (although probably shouldn't) create a matrix with lists by doing something like `v <- list(list(1:2),list(2:4),list(3:7),list(1)); dim(v) <- c(2,2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a data.frame by adding a list as a column.

```
x <- matrix(runif(16,1,100),ncol=4)
xdf <- data.frame(x)
MyList <- list("a"=c(1,4),"b"=c(3,6),"c"=c(4,8,2),"d"=c(7,4))
xdf$MyList <- MyList 
xdf
        X1        X2       X3       X4  MyList
1 39.73090  3.045103 61.45340 86.77167    1, 4
2 90.06798 38.227905 46.19948 70.15402    3, 6
3 90.54852 42.799657 77.85409 89.66850 4, 8, 2
4 65.97255 41.813881 81.49168 51.22093    7, 4

str(xdf[1,5])
List of 1
 $ a: num [1:2] 1 4
# but each cell is a list so to get the length you need
length(xdf[1,5][[1]])
[1] 2
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using a data.frame since it can break a lot of the other usual data.frame functions (such as read.table/write.table). A data.frame is really happiest with truly rectangular data in my opinion. There's no need for one here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all the items in array need to be of the same type. You can make a matrix/array of lists if you like

```
life.obs<-array(list(), dim=c(3,3))
```

And then the important thing to do when placing/retrieving values is to use double brackets to actually access the element. For example

```
life.obs[[i,count+1]] <- life15
```

So this should be true as well

```
length(life.obs[[1,1]]) == 4
# [1] TRUE
```